# Assigning function to IOS button in 2nd view controller based on Table View selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have two view controllers

1. `View Controller A`
2. `View Controller B`

I have a Table View in `View Controller A` that lists out four sounds.  When a user selects one of the sounds, a button in `View Controller B` should be programmed to play that sound.

I have been playing around with `prepareForSeque` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and can't seem to get either one to work correctly.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you're using a segue, then `prepareForSegue` is likely the right place.  What does your code there look like?

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of the selected indexPath in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. A simple way is to create a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

And then store the selected indexPath in that property, after that, call to the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_ID" sender:nil];
}
```

In `prepareForSegue:` get the selected sound form the sounds array:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_ID"])
    {
        ViewControllerB *controller = segue.destinationViewController.
        controller.selectedSound = self.sounds[self.selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

That is in case that the name of the array is `sounds`. You have to create a property in the view controller B to store the sound passed through the segue. Name a segue between the scenes  with the name `SEGUE_ID`. It is obvious that you have to adapt the code to your needs, I'm assuming your array is full of NSString objects referencing the names of your sounds. So, the property `selectedSound` in the last chunk of code have to be an NSString. As I said, it depends of the structure of your array of sounds.

**Edit:** According to the @jlehr comment, the code can be more concise by removing the property in the View Controller A, the line `self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath` and obtaining the selected indexPath with the following instead:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
ViewControllerB *controller = segue.destinationViewController.
controller.selectedSound = self.sounds[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Hmm, I've done all of this and still can't get it to work for some reason. Having trouble figuring out if selectedSound is receiving the string that is passed through.

Comment: The table view tracks selection, so there's no need for its view controller to do so as well. Just call the table view's `indexPathForSelectedRow` method whenever needed.

Comment: Have you tried to place an NSLog in view controller B to see if you get a nil pointer?. Try it and place another to see what you get from the array at the selected indexPath row.